# how to use jquery.before() to insert before Dom elements?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm using this code to insert before all elements in a specific div.

```
 $.post('getcomments.php', {rid:1, frm: 10,to:20}, function(data) {
                            $("#main_post_comments").before(data);
                    });
```

the first time the page loads the function works fine
but after that is always append before the original html element that was written in the original html code not the last appended element that I requested with the $.post

this is the first time the page loads (firs item is comment 102):
[image: The first time the page loads]

This is after inserting the first comment (comment 103 is insrted after 102) correctly:
[image: The first comment]

This is after inserting the second comment (comment 104 also inserted after comment 102)
[image: The second comment]

How to insert the new data before every element in the "#main_post_comments" even if it is inserted dynamically?

Comment: Sounds like you might want `.prepend()` rather than `.before()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use prepend instead of before**

```
  $("#main_post_comments").prepend(data);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$.post('getcomments.php', {rid:1, frm: 10,to:20}, function(data) {
                            $("#main_post_comments").insertBefore(data);
                    });
```

Maybe you are looking for insertBefore();

http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/

Comment: `.insertBefore()` and `.before()` do the same thing but with opposite syntax. The code you've shown will try to insert `#main_post_comments` _before_ `data` but `data` isn't in the DOM yet.

Comment: what is the id for the recent appended sections?
you have to append it to the last section, if the id is allways "main_post_comments" then it will look for it all the times.

so perhaps adding a counter var i and changing id as "#main_post_comments_"+i;